# achartengine bitmap width in remoteview

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a problem with aChartEngine.
Im trying to display graph in home screen widget. So far unsuccessfully, the problem is when I get the bitmap into container it's shrunk and not streched to match container width.
There is data which i see updating but it's like on this image :

[image]

On image is container and graph loaded bitmap filling partially.

When this graph is added like this (to activity) there is no problems:

```
GraphicalView graph = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, getDataSet(dates, values, seriesTitle), getRenderer(context, lblAxisY), "HH:mm");
graphLayout.removeAllViews();
graphLayout.addView(graph, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

When I convert graph to bitmap and return it, it's wrong:

```
float dpi = AndroidResolution.getScreenDpi(context);
        GraphicalView graph = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, getDataSet(dates, values, seriesTitle), getRendererWidget(context,
                lblAxisY), "HH:mm");

        graph.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        graph.layout((int) (0 * dpi), (int) (0 * dpi), (int) (100 * dpi), (int) (100 * dpi));
        graph.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        graph.buildDrawingCache();
        graph.getDrawingCache();

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (100 * dpi), (int) (100 * dpi), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        graph.draw(canvas);

        return bmp;
```

I tried with various values for layout and bitmap size but I get always something distorted and shrunk. I can not get view width and height since it's a remoteview.

Method that recieves bmp:

```
remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imgRecentDetails, AndroidPlot.generateTimePlot(context, values, dates,"VALUES", "AXIS Y")));
```

Renderer code :

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer returningRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    returningRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    returningRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 255, 0));
    returningRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 255, 0));
    returningRenderer.setGridColor(Color.argb(119, 128, 128, 128));
    returningRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    returningRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    returningRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(dpi * 3);
    returningRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(dpi * 3);
    returningRenderer.setYLabels(5);
    returningRenderer.setXLabels(3);
    returningRenderer.setYTitle(lblAxisY);
    returningRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    returningRenderer.setYAxisMax(100);
    returningRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    returningRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);
    returningRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);
    returningRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    returningRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    returningRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    returningRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 1000, 0, 0 });
    returningRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.POINT);
    renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setFillBelowLine(true);
    renderer.setFillBelowLineColor(Color.argb(255, 23, 123, 189));
    returningRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    return returningRenderer;
```

Any insight or solution greatly welcome.

UPDATE: I tried it also in regular activity and it's also shrunk (used graph.toBitmap()) in top left corner of container.

Comment: Dan u're a life saver! Suddenly all is displayed :) 
I've lost hours on debugging. Post it as answer so i can accept

Comment: Cool. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `returningRenderer.setInScroll(false)`.